# How to buy additional storage for legacy Google GSuite

Tags: google-workspace

How I can buy additional storage for the old, legacy and free GSuite package? My current limit is 17GB, but I want to buy more.

Answer (score 1):

Not any more, [according to Google](https://support.google.com/a/answer/12005619?product_name=UnuFlow&visit_id=637969616777795552-1834268180&rd=1&src=supportwidget0): "As of June 2022, the G Suite legacy storage add-ons are no longer available to purchase."

So we can keep using our G Suite Legacy, but only if we never need more than 15GB of storage (for mail, photos, etc.) for any single user.

Google reversed the decision to kill the whole deal because of the blowback, and now trying to kill it quietly and gradually.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding options on how to add Drive storage to Legacy accounts [their documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/177064) shows

> If you have Google Workspace for Nonprofits or the legacy free edition of G Suite, you can upgrade your edition to get more storage. Compare your edition

So directly with Google Workspace the only option you have is to upgrade to the next available subscription which will become paid.

Alternatively, you can go to this URL (using your legacy account) https://drive.google.com/settings/storage and see if it shows you the 'Get More Storage' option, if it does then the purchase can be done via Google Play.